# scrapy spider doesn't scrape information

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning how to use scrapy, and I have come to the problem, my spider doesn't scrape information from a website that I choose. Here is my spider's code:

```py
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from reddit.items import RedditItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor


class RedditSpider(Spider):
   name = "reddit"
   allowed_domains =['http://www.reddit.com']
   start_urls = ["http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/3arta6/awkward_moment_seal/"]
   rules = (
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

   def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="siteTable_t3_3arta6"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
      item = RedditItem()
      item['author'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
      item['score_unvoted'] = site.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "score_unvoted")]/text()').extract()
      item['usertext'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="form-t1_csfkjb86q9"]/text()').extract()
      yield item
```

Here is my items.py:

```py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import sys
if "C:\\Python27" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("C:\\Python27")


class RedditItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
   author = Field()
   score_unvoted = Field()
   usertext = Field()
```

[This is what happens when I use `scrapy crawl reddit` in terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGHmp.jpg)

Any help would be great.

Comment: nothing bad happens you just dont get data because you have bad xpaths you need to learn more about xpaths and write xpaths matching content you extract

Comment: Hm I guess back to square one, thanks for the help.

Comment: tip, xpath for all comments is `//div[contains(@class,'entry')]` and you must use [relative xpaths](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) when iterating